# Counting number of zeros per row by Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame I would like to compute number of zeros per each row. How can I compute it with Pandas?

This is presently what I ve done, this returns indices of zeros

```
def is_blank(x):
    return x == 0 

indexer = train_df.applymap(is_blank)
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use a boolean comparison which will produce a boolean df, we can then cast this to int, True becomes 1, False becomes 0 and then call `count` and pass param `axis=1` to count row-wise:

```
In [56]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,0,1,3], 'b':[0,0,1,0,1], 'c':[0,0,0,0,0]})
df
Out[56]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  1  0  0
4  3  1  0
In [64]:

(df == 0).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
Out[64]:
0    2
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

Breaking the above down:

```
In [65]:

(df == 0)
Out[65]:
       a      b     c
0  False   True  True
1   True   True  True
2   True  False  True
3  False   True  True
4  False  False  True
In [66]:

(df == 0).astype(int)
Out[66]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  1
4  0  0  1
```

**EDIT**

as pointed out by david the `astype` to `int` is unnecessary as the `Boolean` types will be upcasted to `int` when calling `sum` so this simplifies to:

```
(df == 0).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 40):

You can count the zeros per column using the following function of python pandas.
It may help someone who needs to count the particular values per each column

```
df.isin([0]).sum(axis=1)
```

Here df is the dataframe and the value which we want to count is 0

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution using `apply()` and `value_counts()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,0,1,3], 'b':[0,0,1,0,1], 'c':[0,0,0,0,0]})
df.apply( lambda s : s.value_counts().get(key=0,default=0), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                     'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        'C': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                            'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                                'E': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})

[Out]:

   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  0  0
2  1  0  1  0  1
3  1  0  0  0  0
4  1  1  0  0  1
5  0  0  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  1  0
7  0  0  0  0  1
8  0  0  0  1  0
9  0  1  0  0  1
```

Apart from the various answers mentioned before, if the requirement is just using Pandas, another option would be using [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

```
df['Zero_Count'] = df.eq(0).sum(axis=1)

[Out]: 

   A  B  C  D  E  Zero_Count
0  1  0  1  0  0           3
1  1  0  1  0  0           3
2  1  0  1  0  1           2
3  1  0  0  0  0           4
4  1  1  0  0  1           2
5  0  0  1  0  0           4
6  1  0  0  1  0           3
7  0  0  0  0  1           4
8  0  0  0  1  0           4
9  0  1  0  0  1           3
```

However, one can also do it with `numpy` using [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

```
import numpy as np

df['Zero_Count'] = np.sum(df == 0, axis=1)

[Out]:

   A  B  C  D  E  Zero_Count
0  1  0  1  0  0           3
1  1  0  1  0  0           3
2  1  0  1  0  1           2
3  1  0  0  0  0           4
4  1  1  0  0  1           2
5  0  0  1  0  0           4
6  1  0  0  1  0           3
7  0  0  0  0  1           4
8  0  0  0  1  0           4
9  0  1  0  0  1           3
```

Or even using [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) as follows

```
df['Zero_Count'] = np.count_nonzero(df == 0, axis=1)

[Out]:

   A  B  C  D  E  Zero_Count
0  1  0  1  0  0           3
1  1  0  1  0  0           3
2  1  0  1  0  1           2
3  1  0  0  0  0           4
4  1  1  0  0  1           2
5  0  0  1  0  0           4
6  1  0  0  1  0           3
7  0  0  0  0  1           4
8  0  0  0  1  0           4
9  0  1  0  0  1           3
```