# How to count the number of apparition of an exact value on a row from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my problem :

I have this DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,10,0,0,10],
             'B':[10,10,0,0,10]})
```

And I would like to find a way that when I select a row, I count the number of apparition of the value 0.

For example, on row number 0, there is 0 on column A and 10 and column B, so the number of apparition of the value 0 is just 1 (column A).

Does anyone knows a trick to do that?

I though about something like `df.loc[0,:]`... but then I don't really know

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229600/counting-number-of-zeros-per-row-by-pandas-dataframe)):
`df['Count_0'] = (df == 0).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Note that the post contains *when I select a row*.
So the OP wants to count zeroes **only** in this selected row,
not in **each** row.

Answer (score 1):

Define the following function:

```
def zeroesInRow(df, rowNo):
    return df.iloc[rowNo].eq(0).sum()
```

Then call it, for the give DataFrame and row number, e.g.:

```
zeroesInRow(df, 1)
```